# exception scenario handling for input http headers in a REST api using spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

I need to do some validations on the input http headers, trying to write GET http rest api with some http headers, need to validate if one of the headers has specific value, if not throw an exception. I have used http inbound gateway, created error-channel and using service activator to notify error handler, I am getting below error,

**No reply received from error channel within timeout**

My code looks like,

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway 
     request-channel="sampleRequestChannel"
     reply-channel="sampleResponseChannel"
     error-channel="apiErrorChannel"
     reply-timeout="15000"
     supported-methods="GET"
     path="/test/{testId}"
     mapped-request-headers="*"
     payload-expression="#pathVariables.testId">
        <int-http:header name="source" expression="#requestParams[source]"/>
    </int-http:inbound-gateway>
    <int:service-activator input-channel="sampleRequestChannel" ref="testAdapterController" method="getDetails" output-channel="testSourceRouter"/>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="apiErrorChannel" ref="testErrorHandler" method="handleFailedRequest" output-channel="sampleResponseChannel"/>

    <bean id="loadErrorHandler" class="com.test.adapter.controller.TestErrorHandler"/>

    <int:router input-channel="testSourceRouter" expression="headers.source">
        <int:mapping value="ABCD" channel="callABCDChannel"/>
        <!--<int:mapping value="std" channel="intermediateStdChannel"/>-->
    </int:router>
```

I am throwing exception in the code but its not reaching to the output channel even though I tried using output channel as reply channel.
I can see exception being thrown in my console logs but api doesn't throw it as a part of api response. I am pretty sure my understanding of working with spring integration is very limited, just started to work with it.

could someone please help?

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear what you want to do: you say in the begging that you throw exception in case of invalid header, but that you talk about a error handler. So, what is essentially your goal: to re-throw exception to the MVC layer, or handle it on the integration one and return some compensation object into an HTTP response?

Comment: I would like to try it both ways! 1. re-throw exception to the MVC layer - if I try this, it still throws exception to the console rather than as HTTP response. Here is the sample code, @ServiceActivator
    public void handleFailedRequest(Message<MessageHandlingException> message) throws Exception {
        Exception ex = message.getPayload();
        LOGGER.error("Exception : " + ex);
        throw ex;
    }

Comment: for the second scenario, handle it on the integration one and return some compensation object into an HTTP response - could you please help how can I utilize error handler?

Answer (score 0):

To re-throw an exception to MVC there is just enough to not have that `error-channel="apiErrorChannel"` configured.

If you'd like to swallow it and return something else, then your `testErrorHandler` must return that object.

This is going to work as is if all your channels in the flow are `DirectChannel` which is a default type. If it is not, then you must look into this section of the doc and ensure an `errorChannel` downstream as a header: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/error-handling.html#error-handling